# How can I use an x-wav file in Emacs?

Tags: org-mode, bell

I was trying to customize my `org-clock-sound` with a file I took from Wikimedia Commons ([here is the file](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bicycle-bell-1.wav)). I know that Emacs can only play, natively, `.wav` and `.au` files. But apparently, my file is recognized as an "x-wav" file, as I see from my file manager: "Type: WAV audio (audio/x-wav)". When I inspect it with `file`, I get:

```
Bicycle-bell-1.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 24 bit, stereo 44100 Hz
```

Unsurprisingly, when I try to set the variable:

```
(setq org-clock-sound "/home/alessandro/.emacs.d/Bicycle-bell-1.wav")
```

and the bell is triggered, I get the standard "bip", as if `org-clock-sound` was set to `t`.

So, **it seems Emacs cannot recognize it**.

I have found a **workaround solution**:
I tried using an online converter to produce an `.au` file, and **it works**!. Inspecting with the file manager gives "Type: ULAW (Sun) audio (audio/basic)", and with `file`:

```
Bicycle-bell-1.au: Sun/NeXT audio data: 16-bit linear PCM, stereo, 44100 Hz
```

However, I've already written this question, so for the sake of bug-solving, my questions are:

1. Can I **play the x-wav file** on Emacs?
2. Is there a way I can **convert it in `.wav`**? Is the `mailcap.el` library useful in some way?

Thanks for your time!

---

Some additional information that may be useful:

- Calling the function `(play-sound "~/.emacs.d/Bicycle-bell-1.wav")` gives the error

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Invalid sound specification")
  play-sound-internal("~/.emacs.d/Bicycle-bell-1.wav")
  play-sound("~/.emacs.d/Bicycle-bell-1.wav")
  (progn (play-sound "~/.emacs.d/Bicycle-bell-1.wav"))
  eval((progn (play-sound "~/.emacs.d/Bicycle-bell-1.wav")) t)
```

- Calling the function `(play-sound-file "~/.emacs.d/Bicycle-bell-1.wav")` gives the error

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Unsupported WAV file format")
  play-sound-internal((sound :file "~/.emacs.d/Bicycle-bell-1.wav"))
  play-sound((sound :file "~/.emacs.d/Bicycle-bell-1.wav"))
  play-sound-file("~/.emacs.d/Bicycle-bell-1.wav")
  (progn (play-sound-file "~/.emacs.d/Bicycle-bell-1.wav"))
```

Comment: The `Bicycle-bell-1.wav` file is 24-bit and even if your emacs is built with the alsa libraries, they don't seem able to play 24-bit WAV files. You can convert it to 16-bit with `ffmpeg` and try again. See the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on Linux and you are using ALSA, `org-notify` calls `org-clock-play-sound` to (optionally) play a sound. `org-clock-play-sound` uses the `aplay` program (part of the `alsa-utils` package) to play the sound. So from the command line, try `aplay /path/to/Bicycle-bell-1.wav`. If that works, be happy with `(org-clock-play-sound "/path/to/Bicycle-bell-1.wav")`.

`play-sound-file` and its subordinates, `play-sound` and `play-sound-internal`, only come in if the above does *NOT* work. You use it like this:

```el
`(play-sound-file "/path/to/Bicycle-bell-1.wav" 80 "some_device")`
```

where `"some_device"` is a string that specifies an ALSA output device. The last two arguments are optional, but at least in my case, without them I get the error:

```el
(error "No usable sound device driver found")
```

That comes from deep in `play-sound-internal` which is a C function in the file `src/sound.c`. I have no idea what device to use to make it behave however.

The subordinates require a different calling convention. Do `C-h f play-sound` to read about it. The call to `play-sound` should look like this:

```el
(play-sound '(sound :file "/path/to/Bicycle-bell-1.wav" :volume 80 :device "some_device")
```

but here again, I have no idea what `"some_device"` should be to make it behave. I guess it should be an ALSA device and (maybe) you can use `aplay -l` to find out its name, but this is beyond my comfort zone.

In short, if you are on Linux and using ALSA (the latter is almost a certain consequence of the former), then try installing the `alsa-utils` package (whatever it is called in your distro) and check that the `aplay` program is installed. That's the shortest way to bliss.

Otherwise, you will have to do some digging to find an ALSA device that Emacs can initialize and use, and somehow make it the default device so that it can be used from `org-clock-play-sound` without arguments.

If you are *NOT* on Linux, the low level ALSA comments above have to be replaced by even more vague comments about the sound system on *your* platform: I know zilch about them so I'm not going to even try to go there.

EDIT: the file `Bicycle-bell-1.wav` is a 24-bit WAV file. Try converting it to 16-bit and check with `mediainfo` to make sure it is 16-bit:

```sh
$ ffmpeg -i Bicycle-bell-1.wav foo.wav
$ mediainfo foo.wav
...
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
...
```

Also check whether your Emacs has been built with ALSA support:

```sh
ldd $(which emacs) | grep sound
    libasound.so.2 => /lib64/libasound.so.2 (0x00007fce0efec000)
```

If the output is empty, complain to your distro and ask them to build Emacs with ALSA support. Or if you are building your own, install `alsa-lib-devel` (that's the Fedora name: YMMV depending on your distro) and rebuild emacs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
I have the package `pipewire-alsa` installed, not `alsa` directly. So I don't have right now programs like `aplay` or `mediainfo`. However, checking the linked library of Emacs, it uses `libasound.so.2`.

Converting the file with `ffmpeg` and setting to it `org-clock-sound` does not raise an error, but the file is not played (only a "TOC" is hearable).

I noticed I was using function `play-sound` incorrectly. Trying with the correct syntax gives the same results as before (good with `.au`, error with 24 bit x-wav, deep tick with 16 bit)

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's what I get too. You should go ahead and install `alsa-utils` which will give you `aplay`. I think that's the easiest way to resolve the problem (and `aplay` can play 24-bit files).